# Archlinux - Battery detected only on AC plug/unplug

Tags: laptop, battery, arch-linux, acpi

I use Archlinux on a new Dell Inspiron 14.

I need to plug/unplug the power cord to have the battery detected.

For instance, now, the battery icon tells me that no battery is connected and

```
$ ls /sys/class/power_supply/
AC
```

If i plug/unplug the power cord it becomes

```
$ ls /sys/class/power_supply/
AC    BAT0
```

How can I fix this behavior so the battery is correctly detected?

Edit: Here is my `dmesg` output : http://pastebin.com/AfJj2ayi

Comment: Are you experiencing [this issue](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=191&t=90112)? Specifically, is the battery detection malfunctioning after a cold boot? Is your system up-to-date? Please post the output of `dmesg`.

Comment: Yes it seems the same, but not olways after the boot. Sometimes it also disappear after a while. See in the main post for dmesg